# get graph Facebook NSDictionary no Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

view.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

{
    NSMutableArray *fbData,*userInfoArray;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *picture;
    NSString *source;
    NSMutableArray *myObject;
    NSDictionary *dictionary,*userData;

}
```

code is describeDictionary function

```
   void describeDictionary (NSDictionary *dict)
    {

        NSArray *keys;
        int i, count;
        id key, value;

        keys = [dict allKeys];
        count = [keys count];
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            key = [keys objectAtIndex: i];
            value = [dict objectForKey: key];

            NSLog (@"Key: %@ for value: %@", key, value);
            }

    }
```

code is Data

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"xxxx?fields=videos.fields(name,picture,source)"];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                userData = user[@"videos"]; // The result is a dictionary
                 describeDictionary(userData);
            }
        }];
```

code is not Data

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"xxxx?fields=videos.fields(name,picture,source)"];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                userData = user[@"videos"]; // The result is a dictionary

            }
        }];
        describeDictionary(userData);
```

Data should be identical

help me please i am get Facebook graph api 
To retrieve the data used But not available
I do not know what to do then. Find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your last code block:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"xxxx?fields=videos.fields(name,picture,source)"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        userData = user[@"videos"]; // The result is a dictionary

    }
}];
describeDictionary(userData);
```

The `describeDictionary(userData);` line is in the wrong place and that's why it's nil—you haven't completed the graph object request at the point you call `describeDictionary`. It should be like this:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"xxxx?fields=videos.fields(name,picture,source)"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        userData = user[@"videos"]; // The result is a dictionary
        describeDictionary(userData);
    }
}];
```

---

To explain further, look at your original code:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"xxxx?fields=videos.fields(name,picture,source)"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        userData = user[@"videos"]; // The result is a dictionary

    }
}];
describeDictionary(userData);
```

This is the sequence in which the code is executed:

1. First, you create the `FBRequest` object that will be sent to the Facebook API:

   ```
   FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"xxxx?fields=videos.fields(name,picture,source)"];
   ```
2. Next, you tell the request object to call the Facebook API and execute the completion handler **when it has finished**:

   ```
   [request startWithCompletionHandler:... ];
   ```
3. Next you call `describeDictionary`, but `userData` is neither in scope or initialized. **The request's completion handler has not yet been executed** therefore `userData` is `nil` at this point.

   ```
   describeDictionary(userData);
   ```
4. The completion handler is called *asynchronously* when the request has finished. It may have finished successfully—in which case `user` will not be `nil`—or there may be an error condition. If there is no error, you assign the value of the `videos` key of the `user` object to `userData`. **It is only at this point that can you pass `userData` to `describeDictionary`**:

   ```
   ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
       if (!error) {
            userData = user[@"videos"]; 
       }
   }
   ```

You have to call `describeDictionary` from within the completion handle block.

Comment: I am config 
NSDictionary *dictionary,*userData;

Data should be identical

Comment: No, you are calling `describeDictionary` __before__ `userData` has been assigned. I'm expanding my answer with further details.

Comment: Will bring data to Feature More length also.

I will use describeDictionary after userData ?